# How can I get texmaker to pick up my local class file

Tags: texmaker, documentclass-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

I am using (as a newbie) texmaker to create documents on linux.  I am making my first attempt at a local class (hartley.cls), derived from article, but with some minor modifications.  Having seen elsewhere that I should store the class file in the directory  which

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

tells me I have put it in ~/texmf

However as soon as I try and run texmaker on a document which uses this class so I can test things it errors out with

```
! LaTeX Error: File `hartley.cls' not found.
```

So. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can keep custom files in the local working directory (that is, whereever the `.tex` file is.) Or if you put them in `$TEXMFHOME` you should run `texhash`. I think there have been similar questions to this already. Might be worth having a search...

Comment: My current document is in a project directory, whereas the "house style" I am trying to write is aimed at a whole set of documents I want to translate from to latex from several projects.  I have tried searching for for this in depth - the ONLY advice I have seen is putting it ~/texmf and I can't make it work.  Now someone has closed this question saying its an exact duplicate - but I can't find any duplicate of this question and I don't have an answer and no thread in which to discuss what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: I tried running texhash on ~/texmf but it didn't change anything.  $TEXMFHOME is not set to anything - is this a Debian issue - should it have been set

Comment: I set $TEXMFHOME to ~/texmf but it hasn't changed anything

Comment: I eventually found the answer - and it by no means clear in any of the other answers I found.  The answer is that it needs to go in ~/texmf/tex/latex.  This subdirectory hierarchy is important - without it it doesn't work